# How to authenticate user with form authentication in Windows Desktop Application

Tags: c#, winforms, forms-authentication

I have done some work in Asp.NET, and i am quite used with user authentication using [FormAuthentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs)

Now I am working on a desktop application and i want to have something like above in windows form application, I want to create and authenticate users by using the application database or xml whatever it is like i have done it in Asp.NET. So far did not any way to achieve this like i want to.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows desktop application is nothing like an ASP.NET web application.
You cannot call the different forms separately. 
(well you can hack the application, but if you do that, you can just as well remove any password protection) 
Hence forms authentication does not make any sense. 
You can create a login window as startup window, and check username and password against the database. 
And that's about it.
It's a Windows application, you don't need membership provider, forms cookie ticket, etc. because unlike HTTP, Windows desktop applications are not stateless.

PS: If you do a WinForms application, make the login via ActiveDirectory authentication.

Comment: @ Quandary: you make everything crystal clear, i was a bit fuzzy earlier. Thanx for the Help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in using FormsAuthentication with Windows applications. What you can do is to use `Membership`, `MembershipUser` and `Roles` classes. All you need to do is to configure Membership and Roles providers in app.config.

`FormsAuthentication` does not actually authenticate your users. If you call `Authenticate` on `FormsAuthentication` you will see that it is obsolete method and that `Membership.ValidateUser` is used instead.

One drawback of these functionalities is that they are part of `System.Web` namespace which means that you have to use Web functionality inside of your Windows application. But if it can get the job done and fulfills the requirements, then go with it.